# How can I add space as parameter in string in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

How can I add space as parameter in string in python
For example,
If I write:

```
s="test"
print(f" {s:< 5}{s}")
```

Then

```
test     test
```

I want something that

```
w=5
printf(f" {s:<f'{w}'}{s}")
```

Comment: `print(f" {s:<{w}}{s}")` ?

Comment: Also you mean `print` instead of `printf`?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
s = "test"
w = 5
print(f" {s:<{w}}{s}")
```

This should produce the same result as:

```
print(f" {s:<5}{s}")
```

Answer (score 1):

If I have well understood, you want to print w spaces. 
You could do something like : `print(f"{s:<{w}}{s}")`
Else, there is also the method ljust : 
`print(s.ljust(w, " ")+s)`

Answer (score 1):

Instead Try This:

`print(f"{s:<{w}{s}")`

Printf() is nothing in python until you define function named printf() manually. And You can't initialise format specifier inside format specifier.